# Wrapping the Facebook login into RxJS Observables in an Angular2 app

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I want to integrate Facebook login into an Angular 2 app. The Facebook SDK is loaded asynchronously and I want to wrap this async call in an Observable.

```
fbInit() {
 var deferred = Observable.create(observer => {
  this._window.instance.fbAsyncInit = () => {
    this._window.instance.FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    this._window.instance.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    console.log("fbInit");
    observer.next();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 });
 return deferred;
}
```

(this._window.instance returns the window object)

Once this call has succeeded, I want to get the login status of the user by using the FB object, that is put on the global window object. I used RxJs' `bindCallback` function to wrap a normal callback into an Observable.

```
getFbStatus() {
  console.log("getFbStatus");
  return Observable.bindCallback(this._window.instance.FB.getLoginStatus);
}
```

Now I want to consecutively run the async queries one after another:

1) initialize the FB SDK and put `FB` on the global `window` object
2) check login status
3) do stuff depending on login status

Using promises this task would be very simple. After some research I found that `flatMap` or `concat` would solve my problem. Neither attempts were successful. This is what I've tried:

```
const initFb$ = this.fbInit();
const getFbStatus$ = this.getFbStatus();
const combined$ = Observable.concat(initFb$, getFbStatus$);

combined$.subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.error(err)
)
```

When running this, the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLoginStatus' of undefined
```

It seems that `getFbStatus` is called, before the Facebook SDK is loaded.

What am I missing here?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To see how to implement sign up with facebook using angular-2 please check this repo. https://github.com/hirenalken/fb-oauth-angular2-4